# How to remove the from container view without destroying a complex layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit, uicontainerview

I have a scene which is built as on the attached screen

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcNWy.png)

Depending on the selection of a button from the top bar, I'm loading a specific view controller inside a container view. When selection is changed or the user is tapping the 'Back' button at controller then should be removed an intrinsic content of the container.

Code for adding into container view:

```
if (self.containerVC != nil) {
    [self removeController];
}

UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController* firstVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];

[self addChildViewController:firstVC];
[self.containerVieww addSubview:firstVC.view];
firstVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerVieww.bounds.size.width, self.containerVieww.bounds.size.height);
[firstVC.view layoutSubviews];
[firstVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

firstVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.logViewHeight.constant = self.contentView.frame.size.height * 0.9;
    [firstVC.view layoutSubviews];
}];

firstVC.delegate = self;
self.containerVC = firstVC;
```

Code for removing from container view:

```
[self.containerVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.logViewHeight.constant = 0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 }];

[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
[self.containerVC.view removeFromSuperview];    // Caused layout destoying !!!
self.containerVC = nil;
```

After calling 'removeFromSuperview' is disappeared a 'Blue View' in my layout.

**How to remove from the container view without destroying a complex layout?**

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are doing... you're setting `firstVC.modalPresentationStyle`, and then when removing you are calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, but you haven't shown any `presentViewController`? Are you getting any error / warning messages in Debug Console?  Have you used `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the objects after your `Blue View` disappears?

Comment: baaasically you gotta do `[firstVC.view removeFromSuperview];`. What you're removing is NOT what you're adding is all

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. Last time I noticed that the order of calling functions during removing the view is wrong. I have changed them and the error disappeared. So the problem is solved.